# How to equip an item in Two Worlds II?

Tags: two-worlds-2

Two Worlds II has a lot of bugs and I came across it and decided to play more than the first half an hour. I came across a lock and I have lock picks though I have pressed a lot of keys and tried drag-and-drop fruitlessly.

How do I equip an item for use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to equip lockpicks, you simply use them, when you attempt to pick a lock, but you need to have the locksmith skill.

In Two worlds 2, there are three ways to open locked doors/chests:

- pick the lock
- open it with magic (requires ice and enchant cards)
- open it with brute force (approach the lock with your weapon drawn, has a chance to damage your weapon)

You should be able to just press the use-button and these options should be available.

Regarding your item question, you can hotkey items and abilities with the PC version:

open the inventory, highlight the item and press Shift + 1-0 to hotkey it to the corresponding key.

Comment: Thank for answering; I'll try this out later tonight after I finish working. I may have more (separate) questions in the future too. :-)

Comment: Some of it worked but this game is so buggy and I lost all two of my save game files that I'm done, I'm just done...